# Origin of Russian class 6 and class 10 verbs

Tags: historical-linguistics, verbs, russian

In Russian, class 10 contains only a handful of verbs ending in either *-олоть* or *-ороть*.

On the other hand, looking at the list in Wiktionary, class 6 contains only one verbs in *-рать* (*орать*) and none in *-лать*, except some ending in *-брать*, *-драть*, *-срать*, etc.

Am I correct in thinking that these two classes both belonged to class III in Proto-Slavic (*consonant + j + thematic vowel*), and the difference arose only in that in class 10 the preceding consonant is a liquid?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are correct. This is the way how `ъ` vowel morphed in Modern Russian comparing to Proto-Slavic:

```
 P.Sl | Modern Ru | Example
 ъла  |  оло      | г(ъ)лас-голос, х(ъ)ладъ-холод
 ъле  |  оло      | м(ъ)леко-молоко (but: млечный), м(ъ)ладой-молодой, г(ъ)лас-голос
 ъра  |  оро      | г(ъ)радъ-город, в(ъ)рата-ворота, к(ъ)раткий-короткий
                  | ст(ъ)ража-сторож, з(ъ)лато-золото
 ъре  |  ере      | б(ъ)рег-берег (but: прибрежный)
```

This rule is not exhaustive, e.g. in some cases `ъ` has reduced at all:

```
 ч(ъ)резмѣрный - чрезмерный
```

…or expanded into a full-featured `о` or `е`:

```
 п(ъ)рег(ъ)радить – перегородить
```

The grammar rules for verb conjugation retained, so you may safely consider verbs with `-оло-` equivalent to those with `-ла-`, and so on.

See Wikipedia article for [Полногласие](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B5).
Note that even the word "полногласие" itself has reduced vowel that hasn't been morphed: `глас` → `голос`.